# CSS Selectors: Navigating the DOM

Tags: html, css, dom

I had written a webpage utilizing `class` and `id` names for nearly all elements and realized this is probably not the most succinct way to accomplish my styling.  I have been trying to move to a more "DOM Traversing" way of styling but there seems to be issues with one style overwriting another.  For example my navbar looks like the following:

```
<nav>
  <li class="navbar--link"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <ul class="dropdown-custom" id="1">
    <li><a style="color: black" href="#">Client 1</a></li>
    <li><a style="color: black" href="#">Client 2</a></li>
    <li><a style="color: black" href="#">Client 3</a></li>
    <li><a style="color: black" href="#">Client 4</a></li>
  </ul>

  <li class="navbar--link"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <ul class="dropdown-custom" id="2">
    <li><a style="color: black" href="#">Peabody, MA</a></li>
    <li><a style="color: black" href="#">Newton, MA</a></li>
    <li><a style="color: black" href="#">Dallas, TX</a></li>
    <li><a style="color: black" href="#">Houston, TX</a></li>
  </ul>

  <li>LOGO</li>

  <li class="navbar--link"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  <ul class="dropdown-custom" id="3">
    <li><a style="color: black" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a style="color: black" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a style="color: black" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a style="color: black" href="#">4</a></li>
  </ul>

  <li class="navbar--link"><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
  <ul class="dropdown-custom" id="4">
    <li><a style="color: black" href="#">A</a></li>
    <li><a style="color: black" href="#">B</a></li>
    <li><a style="color: black" href="#">C</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

...and I was having trouble styling the `a` within the `ul` without also effecting the `a` outside the `ul`.  I tried using many permutations `nav > ul > li > a` as well as the `+` selector, but was not having any luck.  Is this something I am doing wrong or is there some other way to select ONLY the `li` within a `ul`?

Comment: Post the CSS that you tried that you say isn't working.

Comment: You have inline styling on your anchors. Remove all the inline styling, and you'll be able to change the look with the css with ease ;)

Comment: So you don't want to use the class names in css selectors, is that the constraint you want to work with?

Comment: why do you have `li` outside `ul`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is exactly what you indicated in your question,
Try using 'direct child of'  `>` ,
Try restart the browser and load the page to see if the changes take place.
Also the problem could be that some elements have been styled, 
eg the li have inline styling which has the highest priority compared to external stylesheet.

```css
nav > ul > li > a 
{
 text-decoration:none; 
 }
nav > li > a
{
  color:green;
  }
```

```html
<nav>
  <li class="navbar--link"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <ul class="dropdown-custom" id="1">
    <li><a style="color: black" href="#">Client 1</a></li>
    <li><a style="color: black" href="#">Client 2</a></li>
    <li><a style="color: black" href="#">Client 3</a></li>
    <li><a style="color: black" href="#">Client 4</a></li>
  </ul>

  <li class="navbar--link"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <ul class="dropdown-custom" id="2">
    <li><a style="color: black" href="#">Peabody, MA</a></li>
    <li><a style="color: black" href="#">Newton, MA</a></li>
    <li><a style="color: black" href="#">Dallas, TX</a></li>
    <li><a style="color: black" href="#">Houston, TX</a></li>
  </ul>

  <li>LOGO</li>

  <li class="navbar--link"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  <ul class="dropdown-custom" id="3">
    <li><a style="color: black" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a style="color: black" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a style="color: black" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a style="color: black" href="#">4</a></li>
  </ul>

  <li class="navbar--link"><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
  <ul class="dropdown-custom" id="4">
    <li><a style="color: black" href="#">A</a></li>
    <li><a style="color: black" href="#">B</a></li>
    <li><a style="color: black" href="#">C</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.dropdown-custom > li {
    //style li here
}
```

This would style all li elements inside a div with the class `.dropdown-custom`, with the same style, while not styling any li elements outside the `.dropdown-custom` div.